# Select count of values in column x where columnfoo = y

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to do is for ages but can't seem to do it, it's the follwing:

Select count of values in column x where columnfoo = y

Comment: could you give some sample data and results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expressions within aggregate functions to only aggregate based on a condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN columnfoo = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS y_count
FROM   tbl
```

*If columnfoo = `y`, then factor the row into the count, otherwise, don't add to the count.*

This avoids having to filter out records in your `WHERE` clause in case you also want to work with records where columnfoo is different `y`.

Example: You can count based on different conditions at the same time:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN columnfoo = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS y_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN columnfoo = 'x' THEN 1 END) AS x_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN columnfoo = 'z' THEN 1 END) AS z_count
--     etc..
FROM   tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x) 
FROM table
WHERE columnfoo = y
```

... or more generally,

```
SELECT columnfoo, COUNT(DISTINCT x) 
FROM table
GROUP BY columnfoo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x, COUNT(x) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE columnfoo = y GROUP BY x
```